# Basic or Advanced installation mode choice to skip or use advanced options pages

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I have a Inno Setup based installer that installs three applications, divided in two components. Now the setup asks the user for the installation directory and which components to install.

I want to change the installer add this new choice:

- Basic mode
- Advanced mode

as the first choice.

If the user selects the **Basic mode** the installer should skip path and component choice and just install using default values.

If the user selects the **Advanced mode** the installer should behaves like now.

There's a way to implement this using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom options page using [`CreateInputOptionPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage) for your "mode" selection. And implement [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) to skip the pages when the "Basic" mode is selected.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  ModePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ModePage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpWelcome, 'Installation mode', 'Select installation mode', '', True, False);
  ModePage.Add('Basic mode');
  ModePage.Add('Advanced mode');
  ModePage.Values[0] := True; { Select Basic mode by default }
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  { If "Basic" mode is selected, skip Directory and Components pages }
  Result := 
    ModePage.Values[0] and
    ((PageID = wpSelectDir) or (PageID = wpSelectComponents));
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!