# Skip Preparing to Install Wizard page in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Referring to the question [Basic or Advanced installation mode choice to skip or use advanced options pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58713139/), I need to skip the **Preparing to Install** wizard page now.

In my case this page is displayed because one or more programs are using files that need to be replaced by the installer; so the installer asks to the user if they want the setup to automatically close the applications and restart at the end of the setup.

I need that this page is hide from the setup process in **Basic** mode, and if some files are used, that the setup automatically closes the applications using them without asking anything to the user.

I've tried editing `ShouldSkipPage` as:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean; 
begin 
  { If "Basic" mode is selected, skip Directory and Components pages }
  Result := 
    ModePage.Values[0] and
    ((PageID = wpSelectDir) or (PageID = wpSelectComponents) or (PageID = wpReady) or (PageID = wpPreparing));
end;
```

adding `(PageID = wpPreparing)` but the page still displayed in Basic mode.

Is there a way to implement this using Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ShouldSkipPage` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) is not even called for `wpPreparing`. That page is not to be skipped.

If you still want to skip it, you have to use hacks like these:

- [How to skip all the wizard pages and go directly to the installation process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22183811/850848)
- [Inno Setup - How to close finished installer after a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42391190/850848)

With the first approach, your code would look like:

```pascal
[Code]
const
  BN_CLICKED = 0;
  WM_COMMAND = $0111;
  CN_BASE = $BC00;
  CN_COMMAND = CN_BASE + WM_COMMAND;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  Param: Longint;
begin
  { If Basic mode is selected, skip Preparing page }
  if (CurPageID = wpPreparing) and ModePage.Values[0] then
  begin
    Param := 0 or BN_CLICKED shl 16;
    PostMessage(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle, CN_COMMAND, Param, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just don't do that.  Ever.  It is **absolutely** unacceptable for you to close an arbitrary list of applications without prompting the user.  It's equally impolite to barrel ahead and then require a reboot at the end of the install.  (It's unforgivable to then trigger the reboot without asking.)

What you *can* do is to put some code in the `PrepareToInstall` `[Code]` function which will automatically close *your* application.  This executes before the user is prompted to close apps, so if it was only your apps involved then they will not be prompted.