# Showing custom page depending on task in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Let's say I have this tasks in Inno Setup:

[image]

And this custom page that is showed after the tasks page:

[image]

How can I show the custom page only if one specific task is selected? Let's say *G1 OPT3*, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) or your custom pages's [`TWizardPage.OnShouldSkipPage` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage) to query [`WizardIsTaskSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected).

With `ShouldSkipPage`, the code would be like:

```pascal
var
  TheCustomPage: TWizardPage;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    (PageID = TheCustomPage.ID) and
    (not WizardIsTaskSelected('TheTask'));
end;
```

---

Similar questions:

- [Basic or Advanced installation mode choice to skip or use advanced options pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58713139/850848)
- [Inno Setup conditionally skip the Finished page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40084003/850848)
- [Skip Inno Setup custom page, unless specific radio button is selected on previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75014819/850848)

Comment: Great Martin! It works, thanks a lot!